# Unable to run angular spec tests on Windows 10

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I am trying to run unit tests for an angular component in a Windows machine. 
What I observe is that there are no test launches. There is no error trace  on console either. Following is what I get:

> >ng test my-component
>
> 0% compiling(node:6420) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use 
>     new API on `.hooks` instead
>
> 29 07 2019 16:52:05.121:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
>
> 29 07 2019 16:52:05.124:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
>
> 29 07 2019 16:52:05.129:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
>
> 29 07 2019 16:53:05.132:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
>
> 29 07 2019 16:53:07.135:WARN [launcher]: Chrome was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
>
> 29 07 2019 16:53:09.138:WARN [launcher]: Chrome was not killed by SIGKILL in 2000 ms, continuing.

How to get tests running?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot tell, without looking into your configuration, however try following karma configuration, do npm install with including the dependencies, post this, remove any unnecessary dependencies for you like "puppeteer" etc

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    files: [
      './assets/content-and-assets/mock-google-api.js'
    ],

    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'cobertura', 'text', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputFile: '../../junitreport/credit-check-tests.xml'
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
        ]
      },
      Chrome1: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--disable-web-security',
          '--enable-gpu']
      },
      ChromeDebugging: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--remote-debugging-port=9333']
      },

    },
     browsers: ['ChromeDebugging'],
     singleRun: false
    //browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    //singleRun: true
  });
};
```

Works for me in Win10 as per my requirement.

PS : You can run chrome in headless mode, toggle-comment last two lines.

**EDIT**

I assume you have already installed chrome browser in your machine.( suggested )

In case, you intent not to use browser you can go for PhantomJS, however that is not performance efficient.

[Benchmark](https://hackernoon.com/benchmark-headless-chrome-vs-phantomjs-e7f44c6956c) for reference